# How do I sort in Firebase Realtime databasefrom Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to sort the records by the highest score.
A user has different scores in different records.
Each user's records are collected on a node.
The name of the knot is "Score".
Score contains the calculated scorelar.
For example, for "Adam".
Special for you ; their records must be listed and listed which record is in which order.

**I want to do**
https://screenpresso.com/=wrwQc

***Database;***

```
{
  "Records" : {
    "-L1pFRQg8anT4_-4V60B" : {
      "score" : "510.159",
      "name" :"Adam"

    },
    "-L1pFRQg8anT4_-5S90B" : {
      "score" : "405.02002",
      "name" :"Adam"
    },
    "-L1yBr5zBXAbD0FjzBRs" : {
      "score" : "328.956",
      "name" :"Jayden"
    },
    "-L1yDiwgC36ARfo-98SV" : {
      "score" : "152",
      "name" :"Nicole"
    },
```

**I use something like this.** It reads all the nodes in this database. If the called user does not specify "layout_hide", it works. Displayed if the searched user's data. But this is a performance issue. Stabil does not work.

```
    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child("Records")
            .orderByChild("score")
            .getReference()

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Siralama> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Siralama>()
                    .setQuery(query, Siralama.class)
                    .build();

    final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter siralamaRecyclerViewAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Siralama, MainActivity.SiralamaViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        public MainActivity.SiralamaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.siralama_sizeozel_row, parent, false);
            return new MainActivity.SiralamaViewHolder(view);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(MainActivity.SiralamaViewHolder holder, final int position, Siralama model) {


            if (model.getUid().equals(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())) {
                holder.setScore(model.getScore());

            }else{
                getRef(position).removeValue();
                mSizeOzelList.removeViewAt(position);
                mSizeOzelList.removeAllViews();
                holder.layout_Hide();
               }

        }



    };

    mSizeOzelList.setAdapter(siralamaRecyclerViewAdapter);
    siralamaRecyclerViewAdapter.startListening();
```

Comment: Is this for real time database or firestore? Please add more details to your question.

Comment: Have you searched the doc? What makes you confused from the doc?

Comment: Share us some code.

Comment: @AlexMamo here code.

Comment: Please add aslo you database structure.

Comment: @AlexMamo database structure here

Comment: @FabioVeronese  code here

Comment: @dazza5000 here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Official Documentation on Retrieveing Data from  Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data)

This says

> With Firebase database queries, you can selectively retrieve data
>   based on various factors. To construct a query in your database, you
>   start by specifying how you want your data to be ordered using one of
>   the ordering functions: **orderByChild(), orderByKey(),
>   or orderByValue()**. You can then combine these with five other methods
>   to conduct complex
>   queries: **limitToFirst(), limitToLast(), startAt(), endAt(),
>   and equalTo()**

Comment: Do you want to examine the data I have added.

Comment: If you wish to, you can share!

Comment: Students in a school are taking the math test. There are 3 exams. That means every student has 3 records. And when we make a student private listing. We need to find out what these three records are in order. for example..

Comment: these are the scores which you want to retrieve in a sorted order? If yes then let me see the structure of your realtime database for a sample student with at least 3 different scores.

Comment: yes sorted.there is an example of the database above.
This is the code that enables sorting.  Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child("Records")
            .orderByChild("score")
            .getReference()

Comment: this is a performance issue. So "FireBaseRecyclerView" is the reason why the "layout_hide" function is installed on the screen.

Comment: @KoushikShomChoudhury If i want to sort at last item i saved in the DB i want to display it in the first Like a notification "Last activity get up to First in screen"

Comment: A traditional approach would be to have a **timestamp field** within your object (most people use milliseconds). Having the field, you can sort in both directions by timestamp when querying.